# How can I make a navbar shrink?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m developing a website and I´m interested in developing a navbar which shrinks wahen scrolling down in the page (just on mobile and tablet versions, which I already implemented in mediaqueries styles). The objective is making the logo a little bit smaller when this shrink triggers. I´m attaching as snipped the code for you to see one page where I want it to be implemented.

```css
  body {
    background-color: #121212 !important;
    font-family: 'Fredoka', sans-serif;
  }
  a {
    color: #dad7d7;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  nav {
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35, 0.99);
  }
  .botoncopyright,
  .botoncopyright:hover {
    color: #ccd1d1;
  }
  footer {
    background-color: #232323;
  }

  .cookie-container {
    background-color: #232323;
    color: #dad7d7;
  }
  .cookie-container a {
    color: #dad7d7;
  }
  .cookie-container a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .cookie-btn {
    background-color: #add8e6;
    color: #232323 !important;
  }
  .cookie-btn:hover {
    background-color: #87c9de;
  }

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  gap: 2vw;
}

a {
  color: #dad7d7;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35, 0.99);
  backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.botoncopyright,
.botoncopyright:hover {
  color: #ccd1d1;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
}

footer {
  background-color: #232323;
}

.cookie-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #363636;
  color: #dad7d7;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.cookie-container.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.cookie-container p {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.cookie-container a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #dad7d7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cookie-container a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.cookie-btn {
  background-color: #add8e6;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #232323 !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cookie-btn:hover {
  background-color: #87c9de;
}

footer .btn svg {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.rsyoutube {
  fill: #8b8d90;
}

.rsyoutube:hover {
  fill: #ff0000;
}

.rstwitter {
  fill: #8b8d90;
}

.rstwitter:hover {
  fill: #00acee;
}

.rsinstagram {
  fill: #8b8d90;
}

.rsinstagram:hover {
  fill: #de1b85;
}

.rstelegram {
  fill: #8b8d90;
}

.rstelegram:hover {
  fill: #229ed9;
}

.rsdiscord {
  fill: #8b8d90;
}

.rsdiscord:hover {
  fill: #5865f2;
}

df-messenger {
  --df-messenger-bot-message: #e1f2f7;
  --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #add8e6;
  --df-messenger-button-titlebar-font-color: #4b4b4b;
  --df-messenger-chat-background-color: #232323;
  --df-messenger-font-color: #232323;
  --df-messenger-send-icon: #add8e6;
  --df-messenger-user-message: #add8e6;
}

df-messenger:hover {
  --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #87c9de;
}

.content {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 2200px;
  width: 96vw;
}

.cookie-wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 30px, #292929 0) top left, linear-gradient(-315deg, transparent 30px, #292929 0) bottom left;
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 38px;
}

.cookie-wrapper h1,
.cookie-wrapper h2 {
  margin: 1.8em 0 47px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #d2d2d2;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.cookie-wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cookie-wrapper h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
}

.cookie-wrapper p {
  color: #d2d2d2;
  text-align: justify;
}

.cookie-wrapper .actualizacion {
  color: #d2d2d2;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 1.5em 0 2em;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.toggle a {
  color: #dad7d7;
}

.toggle a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu,
.submenu {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.logo {
  padding: 7.5px 0 7.5px 0;
}

.botonlogo {
  max-width: 56px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item.button {
  padding: 9px 5px;
}

.item:not(.button) a:hover,
.item a:hover::after {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 5px;
}

.menu li.subitem a {
  padding-right: -15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

.toggle {
  order: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.item.button {
  order: 2;
}

.item {
  order: 3;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.active .item {
  display: block;
}

.button.secondary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dad7d7;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu-active .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.has-submenu>a::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  content: '\f024';
  color: #dad7d7;
  padding-left: 11px;
}

.subitem a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.submenu-active {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #363636;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

li.has-submenu a {
  color: #dad7d7 !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.has-submenu a:hover {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.subitem a {
  padding-left: 0%;
  padding-right: 33px !important;
  width: 100%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 700px) {

  .menu {
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .logo {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .item.button {
    width: auto;
    order: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  .toggle {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
    order: 2;
  }
  .menu li.button a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  .button a {
    background-color: #add8e6;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1.5px solid #add8e6;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    transition: 0.8s;
  }
  .button.secondary {
    border: 0;
  }
  .button.secondary a {
    background-color: #add8e6;
    border: 1.5px solid #add8e6;
    transition: 0.8s;
  }
  .button a:hover {
    background-color: #87c9de;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #474747;
    transition: 0.8s;
  }
  .button:not(.secondary) a:hover {
    border: 1.5px solid #87c9de;
    transition: 0.8s;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  
  .cookie-wrapper {
    background: linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 45px, #292929 0) top left, linear-gradient(-315deg, transparent 45px, #292929 0) bottom left;
    background-size: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .item {
    order: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }

  .button {
    order: 2;
  }

  .submenu-active .submenu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 68px;
    background-color: #363636;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  }

  .toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .boton {
    background-color: #add8e6;
    border: none;
    color: #585858 !important;
  }
  .boton:hover {
    background-color: #87c9de;
    border: none;
    color: #585858 !important;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="preload" href="css/cookies.css" as="style" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Cookies - Mixi</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d48f664aec.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cookies.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <main>

      <nav>

        <ul class="menu">

          <li class="logo">
            <a class="botonlogo" href="https://www.mixi.es"><svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 99 99" enable-background="new 0 0 99 99" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#ACD7E4" d="M85.95,98.88H12.37c-6.78,0-12.28-5.5-12.28-12.28V13.02c0-6.78,5.5-12.28,12.28-12.28h73.58c6.78,0,12.28,5.5,12.28,12.28V86.6C98.23,93.38,92.73,98.88,85.95,98.88z" /><g><g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M7.96,66.3c-0.68,0-1.17-0.11-1.49-0.32s-0.53-0.5-0.64-0.85c-0.11-0.35-0.16-0.78-0.16-1.28v-21.1c0-0.46,0.05-0.86,0.16-1.2c0.11-0.34,0.33-0.59,0.67-0.77s0.84-0.27,1.52-0.27c0.78,0,1.34,0.15,1.68,0.45c0.34,0.3,0.51,0.83,0.51,1.57l-0.21,2.29c0.25-0.53,0.62-1.07,1.12-1.6c0.5-0.53,1.09-1.01,1.79-1.44c0.69-0.43,1.43-0.76,2.21-1.01c0.78-0.25,1.58-0.37,2.4-0.37c1.24,0,2.35,0.22,3.33,0.67c0.98,0.44,1.86,1.07,2.64,1.89c0.78,0.82,1.44,1.83,1.97,3.04c0.71-1.17,1.46-2.17,2.26-3.01c0.8-0.83,1.71-1.47,2.72-1.92c1.01-0.44,2.16-0.67,3.44-0.67c2.06,0,3.77,0.51,5.14,1.52c1.37,1.01,2.4,2.43,3.09,4.26c0.69,1.83,1.04,4.02,1.04,6.58v11.13c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.32,0.63-0.64,0.83s-0.83,0.29-1.54,0.29c-0.67,0-1.19-0.11-1.54-0.32c-0.36-0.21-0.58-0.5-0.67-0.85c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V52.72c0-1.56-0.2-2.93-0.59-4.1c-0.39-1.17-0.96-2.08-1.71-2.72c-0.75-0.64-1.72-0.96-2.93-0.96c-1.28,0-2.41,0.32-3.38,0.96c-0.98,0.64-1.73,1.54-2.26,2.69s-0.8,2.53-0.8,4.13v11.24c0,0.53-0.11,1-0.32,1.39c-0.21,0.39-0.53,0.67-0.96,0.83c-0.43,0.16-0.96,0.19-1.6,0.08c-0.53-0.04-0.94-0.17-1.23-0.4s-0.46-0.51-0.53-0.85c-0.07-0.34-0.11-0.72-0.11-1.15V52.72c0-1.56-0.19-2.93-0.56-4.1s-0.94-2.08-1.71-2.72c-0.76-0.64-1.75-0.96-2.96-0.96c-1.28,0-2.41,0.33-3.38,0.99c-0.98,0.66-1.73,1.57-2.26,2.74c-0.53,1.17-0.8,2.52-0.8,4.05v11.19c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.63-0.67,0.83C9.2,66.2,8.67,66.3,7.96,66.3z" /><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M52.23,34.12c-0.78,0-1.37-0.12-1.76-0.35c-0.39-0.23-0.65-0.56-0.77-0.99c-0.12-0.43-0.19-0.92-0.19-1.49c0-0.57,0.06-1.06,0.19-1.46c0.12-0.41,0.39-0.71,0.8-0.91c0.41-0.2,1-0.29,1.78-0.29c0.75,0,1.31,0.11,1.71,0.32s0.65,0.53,0.77,0.96c0.12,0.43,0.19,0.94,0.19,1.54c0,0.53-0.06,1-0.19,1.41c-0.12,0.41-0.38,0.72-0.77,0.93C53.6,34.02,53.01,34.12,52.23,34.12z M52.23,66.3c-0.67,0-1.19-0.1-1.54-0.29c-0.36-0.2-0.58-0.47-0.67-0.83c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V42.86c0-0.46,0.05-0.88,0.16-1.25s0.33-0.65,0.67-0.83c0.34-0.18,0.86-0.27,1.57-0.27c0.67,0,1.17,0.1,1.49,0.29c0.32,0.2,0.53,0.48,0.64,0.85c0.11,0.37,0.16,0.81,0.16,1.3v20.99c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.62-0.67,0.8C53.42,66.21,52.91,66.3,52.23,66.3z" /></g></g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M65.03,57.61l-4.59,5c-0.52,0.57-0.88,1.05-1.08,1.43c-0.2,0.39-0.2,0.75,0,1.09c0.2,0.34,0.56,0.7,1.08,1.09c0.52,0.35,0.97,0.59,1.35,0.72c0.38,0.12,0.77,0.08,1.17-0.13c0.4-0.21,0.86-0.58,1.38-1.12l7.42-8.08H65.03z" /><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M84.36,64.04c-0.18-0.39-0.55-0.87-1.11-1.43l-8.04-8.76l8.1-8.83c0.56-0.57,0.92-1.05,1.08-1.43c0.16-0.39,0.14-0.75-0.06-1.09c-0.2-0.34-0.58-0.72-1.14-1.14c-0.76-0.57-1.38-0.81-1.86-0.72c-0.48,0.09-1.12,0.52-1.92,1.3l-7.56,8.24l-7.56-8.24c-0.48-0.53-0.9-0.9-1.26-1.12c-0.36-0.21-0.73-0.27-1.11-0.16c-0.38,0.11-0.83,0.34-1.35,0.69c-0.6,0.39-1,0.75-1.2,1.09c-0.2,0.34-0.21,0.71-0.03,1.12c0.18,0.41,0.53,0.89,1.05,1.46l8.1,8.83l-0.01,0.01l3.37,3.67l0.01-0.01l7.5,8.18c0.56,0.53,1.04,0.9,1.44,1.12c0.4,0.21,0.79,0.26,1.17,0.13c0.38-0.12,0.81-0.36,1.29-0.72c0.56-0.39,0.93-0.75,1.11-1.09C84.54,64.79,84.54,64.43,84.36,64.04z" /></g><g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M90.03,34.55c-0.78,0-1.37-0.11-1.76-0.35c-0.39-0.23-0.65-0.56-0.77-0.99c-0.12-0.43-0.19-0.92-0.19-1.49c0-0.57,0.06-1.06,0.19-1.47c0.12-0.41,0.39-0.71,0.8-0.91c0.41-0.19,1-0.29,1.79-0.29c0.75,0,1.31,0.11,1.7,0.32c0.39,0.21,0.65,0.53,0.77,0.96s0.19,0.94,0.19,1.54c0,0.53-0.06,1-0.19,1.41c-0.12,0.41-0.38,0.72-0.77,0.93C91.4,34.44,90.81,34.55,90.03,34.55z M90.03,66.72c-0.67,0-1.19-0.1-1.54-0.29c-0.36-0.2-0.58-0.47-0.67-0.83c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V43.28c0-0.46,0.05-0.88,0.16-1.25c0.11-0.37,0.33-0.65,0.67-0.83s0.86-0.27,1.57-0.27c0.67,0,1.17,0.1,1.49,0.29c0.32,0.2,0.53,0.48,0.64,0.85s0.16,0.81,0.16,1.31v20.99c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.62-0.67,0.8C91.21,66.63,90.71,66.72,90.03,66.72z" /></g></g></g></svg></a>        
          </li>

          <li class="item"><a href="tienda">Tienda</a></li>

          <li class="item"><a href="calculadora">Calculadora</a></li>

          <li class="item"><a href="noticias">Noticias</a></li>

          <li class="item"><a href="contacto">Contacto</a></li>

          <li class="item has-submenu">

            <a tabindex="0">Idioma: ES</a>

            <ul class="submenu">

              <li class="subitem"><a href="en/cookies">English</a></li>

            </ul>

          </li>

          <li class="toggle">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
          </li>

          <script src="js/toggle.js"></script>

        </ul>

      </nav>

      <div class="content">

        <div class="cookie-wrapper">

          <br />

          <h1>Política de cookies y privacidad - Mixi</h1>

          <h2>¿Qué son las cookies?</h2>

          <p>En primer lugar, las cookies son pequeñas cantidades de información almacenadas en el navegador web para cada usuario que utilice una página web que cuente con cookies, haciendo de los sitios web elementos fáciles de utilizar y que en ningún momento
            dañará el dispositivo donde se guarden.</p>

          <p>La información guardada como cookies podrán ser elementos como la hora y tiempo de visita a la página, pero nunca permitiendo por cuestiones de seguridad la transferencia física de esta información a otro dispositivo que no sea en el que aceptaron
            originalmente dichas cookies.</p>

          <p>Las cookies que permiten identificar a una persona, se consideran datos personales de la misma, por lo que deberán ser aceptadas por el usuario para que el sitio web pueda tratarlas.</p>

          <h2>Cookies de terceros</h2>

          <p>Las cookies de terceros, son utilizadas y gestionadas por entidades externas que proporcionan a la plataforma servicios determinados para mejorar el sitio web y la experiencia final del usuario que lo utilice. Los objetivos de este tipo de cookies
            son la obtención de estadísticas de accesos y comprobar la interacción del usuario con la web.</p>

          <p>La información obtenida, se refiere al número de páginas visitadas, el idioma, el lugar a la que pertenece la dirección IP desde la que visita el usuario el sitio, el número de usuarios que acceden y con qué frecuencia lo hacen, el tiempo de visita,
            navegador utilizado y el tipo de dispositivo desde el que realizan la visita. Esta información es posteriormente enviada exclusivamente a la plataforma para contrastarla y poder así mejorar la experiencia futura del usuario incorporando o retirando
            características que harán de esta página un sitio web mejor y adaptado para la mayoría de usuarios una vez adaptadas estas métricas.</p>

          <h2>Cookies orientadas a redes sociales</h2>

          <p>A lo largo de la página se incorporan accesos a redes sociales. Por esta razón, las cookies de redes sociales pueden almacenarse en el navegador en conjunto con las cookies de esta web (una vez aceptadas ambas ellas). Cada red social dispone de
            sus propias políticas de protección de datos y cookies, siendo ellos mismos responsables de sus propias prácticas de privacidad y cookies. El usuario debe referirse a las mismas para informarse acerca de dichas cookies y, en su caso, del tratamiento
            de sus datos personales que conllevan.</p>

          <h2>Deshabilitar, rechazar y eliminar cookies almacenadas</h2>

          <p>El usuario que use esta plataforma tiene siempre la opción de deshabilitar y eliminar las cookies instaladas en su dispositivo mediante la configuración de su navegador (con la pérdida de algunos servicios al hacerlo). En este sentido, los procedimientos
            para eliminar las cookies pueden diferir de un navegador a otro, por lo que el usuario debe acudir a las instrucciones facilitadas por el propio navegador que esté utilizando para esta tarea.</p>

          <p class="actualizacion">Políticas creadas y actualizadas por MIXI - Julio de 2022.</p>

          <br/>

        </div>

      </div>

      <footer class="text-center text-white">

        <div class="container pt-4">

          <section class="mb-4">

            <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating btn-lg text-dark m-1" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsJSqbYBZ48kx71kCdR1lfQ" target="_blank" role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" class="rsyoutube" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19.615 3.184c-3.604-.246-11.631-.245-15.23 0-3.897.266-4.356 2.62-4.385 8.816.029 6.185.484 8.549 4.385 8.816 3.6.245 11.626.246 15.23 0 3.897-.266 4.356-2.62 4.385-8.816-.029-6.185-.484-8.549-4.385-8.816zm-10.615 12.816v-8l8 3.993-8 4.007z" /></svg></a>

            <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating btn-lg text-dark m-1" href="https://twitter.com/mixi_esp" target="_blank" role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" class="rstwitter bi bi-twitter" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M5.026 15c6.038 0 9.341-5.003 9.341-9.334 0-.14 0-.282-.006-.422A6.685 6.685 0 0 0 16 3.542a6.658 6.658 0 0 1-1.889.518 3.301 3.301 0 0 0 1.447-1.817 6.533 6.533 0 0 1-2.087.793A3.286 3.286 0 0 0 7.875 6.03a9.325 9.325 0 0 1-6.767-3.429 3.289 3.289 0 0 0 1.018 4.382A3.323 3.323 0 0 1 .64 6.575v.045a3.288 3.288 0 0 0 2.632 3.218 3.203 3.203 0 0 1-.865.115 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-.614-.057 3.283 3.283 0 0 0 3.067 2.277A6.588 6.588 0 0 1 .78 13.58a6.32 6.32 0 0 1-.78-.045A9.344 9.344 0 0 0 5.026 15z" /></svg></a>

            <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating btn-lg text-dark m-1" href="https://www.instagram.com/mixi_esp/" target="_blank" role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" class="rsinstagram bi bi-instagram" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M8 0C5.829 0 5.556.01 4.703.048 3.85.088 3.269.222 2.76.42a3.917 3.917 0 0 0-1.417.923A3.927 3.927 0 0 0 .42 2.76C.222 3.268.087 3.85.048 4.7.01 5.555 0 5.827 0 8.001c0 2.172.01 2.444.048 3.297.04.852.174 1.433.372 1.942.205.526.478.972.923 1.417.444.445.89.719 1.416.923.51.198 1.09.333 1.942.372C5.555 15.99 5.827 16 8 16s2.444-.01 3.298-.048c.851-.04 1.434-.174 1.943-.372a3.916 3.916 0 0 0 1.416-.923c.445-.445.718-.891.923-1.417.197-.509.332-1.09.372-1.942C15.99 10.445 16 10.173 16 8s-.01-2.445-.048-3.299c-.04-.851-.175-1.433-.372-1.941a3.926 3.926 0 0 0-.923-1.417A3.911 3.911 0 0 0 13.24.42c-.51-.198-1.092-.333-1.943-.372C10.443.01 10.172 0 7.998 0h.003zm-.717 1.442h.718c2.136 0 2.389.007 3.232.046.78.035 1.204.166 1.486.275.373.145.64.319.92.599.28.28.453.546.598.92.11.281.24.705.275 1.485.039.843.047 1.096.047 3.231s-.008 2.389-.047 3.232c-.035.78-.166 1.203-.275 1.485a2.47 2.47 0 0 1-.599.919c-.28.28-.546.453-.92.598-.28.11-.704.24-1.485.276-.843.038-1.096.047-3.232.047s-2.39-.009-3.233-.047c-.78-.036-1.203-.166-1.485-.276a2.478 2.478 0 0 1-.92-.598 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-.6-.92c-.109-.281-.24-.705-.275-1.485-.038-.843-.046-1.096-.046-3.233 0-2.136.008-2.388.046-3.231.036-.78.166-1.204.276-1.486.145-.373.319-.64.599-.92.28-.28.546-.453.92-.598.282-.11.705-.24 1.485-.276.738-.034 1.024-.044 2.515-.045v.002zm4.988 1.328a.96.96 0 1 0 0 1.92.96.96 0 0 0 0-1.92zm-4.27 1.122a4.109 4.109 0 1 0 0 8.217 4.109 4.109 0 0 0 0-8.217zm0 1.441a2.667 2.667 0 1 1 0 5.334 2.667 2.667 0 0 1 0-5.334z" /></svg></a>

            <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating btn-lg text-dark m-1" href="https://t.me/mixiesp" target="_blank" role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" class="rstelegram bi bi-telegram" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.287 5.906c-.778.324-2.334.994-4.666 2.01-.378.15-.577.298-.595.442-.03.243.275.339.69.47l.175.055c.408.133.958.288 1.243.294.26.006.549-.1.868-.32 2.179-1.471 3.304-2.214 3.374-2.23.05-.012.12-.026.166.016.047.041.042.12.037.141-.03.129-1.227 1.241-1.846 1.817-.193.18-.33.307-.358.336a8.154 8.154 0 0 1-.188.186c-.38.366-.664.64.015 1.088.327.216.589.393.85.571.284.194.568.387.936.629.093.06.183.125.27.187.331.236.63.448.997.414.214-.02.435-.22.547-.82.265-1.417.786-4.486.906-5.751a1.426 1.426 0 0 0-.013-.315.337.337 0 0 0-.114-.217.526.526 0 0 0-.31-.093c-.3.005-.763.166-2.984 1.09z" /></svg></a>

            <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating btn-lg text-dark m-1" href="https://discord.gg/UZc4JHhvZu" target="_blank" role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" class="rsdiscord bi bi-discord" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M13.545 2.907a13.227 13.227 0 0 0-3.257-1.011.05.05 0 0 0-.052.025c-.141.25-.297.577-.406.833a12.19 12.19 0 0 0-3.658 0 8.258 8.258 0 0 0-.412-.833.051.051 0 0 0-.052-.025c-1.125.194-2.22.534-3.257 1.011a.041.041 0 0 0-.021.018C.356 6.024-.213 9.047.066 12.032c.001.014.01.028.021.037a13.276 13.276 0 0 0 3.995 2.02.05.05 0 0 0 .056-.019c.308-.42.582-.863.818-1.329a.05.05 0 0 0-.01-.059.051.051 0 0 0-.018-.011 8.875 8.875 0 0 1-1.248-.595.05.05 0 0 1-.02-.066.051.051 0 0 1 .015-.019c.084-.063.168-.129.248-.195a.05.05 0 0 1 .051-.007c2.619 1.196 5.454 1.196 8.041 0a.052.052 0 0 1 .053.007c.08.066.164.132.248.195a.051.051 0 0 1-.004.085 8.254 8.254 0 0 1-1.249.594.05.05 0 0 0-.03.03.052.052 0 0 0 .003.041c.24.465.515.909.817 1.329a.05.05 0 0 0 .056.019 13.235 13.235 0 0 0 4.001-2.02.049.049 0 0 0 .021-.037c.334-3.451-.559-6.449-2.366-9.106a.034.034 0 0 0-.02-.019Zm-8.198 7.307c-.789 0-1.438-.724-1.438-1.612 0-.889.637-1.613 1.438-1.613.807 0 1.45.73 1.438 1.613 0 .888-.637 1.612-1.438 1.612Zm5.316 0c-.788 0-1.438-.724-1.438-1.612 0-.889.637-1.613 1.438-1.613.807 0 1.451.73 1.438 1.613 0 .888-.631 1.612-1.438 1.612Z" /></svg></a>
          </section>
          
        </div>

        <div class="text-center text-dark p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
          <a class="botoncopyright">Mixi &copy; | 2022</a>
        </div>
        
      </footer>

    </main>

    <div class="cookie-container">

      <p>Este sitio usa cookies para el funcionamiento de servicios proporcionados y analiza el tráfico de la web para mejorar.</p>

      <a class="d-flex align-items-center" href="https://www.mixi.es/cookies">Más información<i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-2"></i></a>

      <button class="cookie-btn">Aceptar</button>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>

    <df-messenger chat-title="Mixi" agent-id="41fe496c-6e3a-4316-aa5a-05dae8cd911d" language-code="es"></df-messenger>

    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-229317979-1"></script>

    <script>

      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'UA-229317979-1');
    </script>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script src="js/utilidades.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Give an id to the menu element and try this,

document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
 document.getElementById('scrollMenu').style.height = 10px;
});

Answer (score 0):

I used  Intersection Observer to do what you what you can add the code to your project

```js
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const sectionOne = document.querySelector("#home");

const sectionOneOptions = {
  rootMargin: "-200px 0px 0px 0px"
};

const sectionOneObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(
  entries,
  sectionOneObserver
) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      header.classList.add("nav-scrolled");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("nav-scrolled");
    }
  });
},
sectionOneOptions);

sectionOneObserver.observe(sectionOne);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
}

header.nav-scrolled {
  height: 45px;
}

header.nav-scrolled .logo {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu span {
  width: 80%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
}

header.nav-scrolled .menu {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#about {
   background-color: gray;
}

#gallery {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

#services {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</header>
  <section id="home">Home</section>
  <section id="about">About</section>
  <section id="gallery">Gallery</section>
  <section id="services">Services</section>
```